# Redirect User to Login Page if Email is Confirmed

Tags: php, javascript, html

So on my website I send out emails with links that the user must follow to verify his/her email. If the user clicks the link in the email, I want the user to be taken to a page that thanks him/her for confirming his/her account, and then redirect the user to the login page. How can I do this? I tried using the PHP header function but this doesn't work because I must send headers to display the "thank you" message, so I can't use that function. What can I do to get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a meta refresh to do the redirect after a set period of time. To redirect in 5 seconds, place this code in the `<head>` of your web page:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;URL='http://example.com/'">
```

You can also do this with an HTTP header:

```
header('Refresh: 5;URL='http://example.com/');
```

Or use JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function delayedRedirect(){
    window.location = "http://example.com/"
}
</script>
<body onLoad="setTimeout('delayedRedirect()', 3000)">
```

Comment: Is there a way to only redirect the page if a certain php value evaluates to true? Can I put a PHP if test around this tag?

Comment: Definitely. If their test fails you can simply not do any of the above.

Comment: Could I just include the meta tag in `<? if(variable){ meta tag } ?>` code?

Answer (score 0):

try php sleep() function 
[enter link description here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php)

you may use like this

```
<?php

if(email code validation evaluates to true by comparing to DB record)
{
echo"thank you message"
sleep(20);
header('location:http://www.somesite.com/login.php');
}
?>
```

if its giving some header error. use ob_start() just after

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is probably to use GET.

The way this works is that you send a link with GET-variables, that you can extract with php and activate the email adress.

E.g. if the user receives the link: 
http://example.com/verifymail.php?email=johndoe@example.com&verify=true

then the script at example.com/verifymail.php can access the email and verify variables like so:

```
<?php
  if($_GET['verify'] == 'true'){
    verifyEmail($_GET['email']);
  }
?>
```

you can form the link in any language, just follow the convention:
- ? after the URL tells php that GET-variables follow. Variables come in name=value pairs. and variables are separated by &